# What are the poetic devices used in this sentence?

Tags: poetry, poetic-devices

In the following sentence, I'm hesitant toward which of these devices: Assonance, consonance, alliteration, repetition and rhyme is/are being used with the bold words.

"*Then I bethought me of a **crutch**, the **shape** being **much** the **same**, and I borrowed one in the village.*"

Comment: Dickens's *Great Expectations* (Chapter XVI) is not usually regarded as a poem

Comment: *Great Expectations* not being a poem is (perhaps was) no barrier to Dickens'  employment of poetic devices.  Much English prose (I suspect prose in other languages too) makes use of poetic devices.